# What does אחדשה"ט stand for?

Tags: acronyms

I received a letter that began with the date, my name, and then on it's own line "אחדשה"ט", then the content of the letter. Any clue as to what it stands for/means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

אחר דרישת שלומו הטוב

After seeking his [i.e. the recipient’s] wellbeing